# Facebook pixel purchase body event

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, for-loop, facebook-pixel

I am trying to make an purchase facebookEvent which it takes an array of objects "Products" that contains the id and the quantity of each product on this array, what I am asking about here that I tried allot to looping into the array of products inside the payload of the event but the compiler has complained, could any one help by how to make the contents array responsive with the array of the whole product ?

```
  //fbp
  (<any>window).fbq("track", "Purchase", {
    value: this.totalPrice,
    currency: "EGP",
    contents: [
      {
        // this should be applicable for every single item on the arrayOfProducts
        id: arrayOfProducts[0].id,
        quantity: arrayOfProducts[0].quantity
      }
    ],
    content_type: "product"
  });
```

Comment: I assume arrayOfProducts is an array? You probably need to use 'map' to transform it into an array of id and quantity structure - you can't just do .id on the array like that.

Comment: I had an syntax error so you didn't got what i meant, could you please take a look again and give me your feedback?

Comment: OK, that's better: I'd guess that would work? What's the problem now? If you get a specific error, either at runtime or compile time, can you edit that into the question too?

Comment: What i mean by my questions is, how to push the whole arrayOfProducts instead of passing only the first item on the array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What i mean by my questions is, how to push the whole arrayOfProducts instead of passing only the first item on the array ?

Use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
//fbp
  (<any>window).fbq("track", "Purchase", {
    value: this.totalPrice,
    currency: "EGP",
    contents: arrayOfProducts.map(function(item) {
        return {
           id: item.id,
           quantity: item.quantity
        }
    }),
    content_type: "product"
  });
```